# A hollow cone in vpython?

Tags: vpython

Do any of you know vpython?
If so how can you create a hollow cone in vpython? Thanks in advance!

I tried creating one, but I don't really understand the working behind an extrusion. Sorry for the basic question, but I really don't know it.

Answer (score 2):

You could use vertex and triangle objects, with the vertex at the tip being shared among all the triangles:

http://www.glowscript.org/docs/VPythonDocs/triangle.html

Comment: You could also make a thin shape at an angle and use a circular path to extrude that thin shape around to form the surface of a hollow cone.